# Facebook api - login problem

Tags: android, facebook

I want to use facebook api in my android application only for status updates in my application content.

First i made an api key from facebook api website and then developed a layout but still i have problem ... that is, i can login only once time and not the second time.

Can you help me use the login api's of facebook correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah.. once you login, you can't populate webview login dialog or facebook native login because 
your access_token is vaild. when your token is valid, login process is automatically done. 
You can change facebook library But I would not recommand that.
 If you want to invalid your access_token, you simply have to logout. 
I believe you can find well documented logout function from hackbook example or 
facebook developer site.

```
    Facebook mFacebook = new Facebook(myAppId);
    AsyncFacebookRunner asyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
                        asyncRunner.logout(context, new LogoutRequestListener());
```

This is from facebook API source. hope this helps.